# PHP get the name of arrays in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a simple multidimensional array with two other arrays in it.

```
<?php
            $data = array(
              'first_array' => array(
                'name' => 'Test1',
                'description' => '...',
              ),
              'second_array' => array(
                'title' => 'Test2',
                'description' => '...',
              )
            );
        ?>
```

And I have a simple foreach array like this:

```
 function show($data, $id){

                 foreach ($data as $course) {

                 }

            }
```

How can I display (and get) the name of the array in every iteration (I mean if it is 'first_array' or 'second_array', not the name fields in the arrays).

Comment: Besides the answers below, take a look at [array_keys($arr)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `key=>val` syntax

```
foreach ($data as $key=>$course) {
    echo $key;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this syntax for foreach :

```
foreach ($data as $name => $course) {
    //do sth
}
```